# узнать тип данных переменной на c++

Tags: c++

Новичок в c++ хочу определить тип данных переменной но вылетает ошибка - invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'
код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    float var = 3.14;
    char str = "a";
    int integer = 10;

    cout << typeid(var).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(str).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(integer).name() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `char str = 'a';`

Comment: `const char *str = "a";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот правильный код, вам надо было заменить `char str = "a";` на `char str = 'a';` потому что char передает символ, а не слово, я тоже новичек, так что могу не правильно сформулировать объяснение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float var = 3.14;
    char str = 'a';
    int integer = 10;

    cout << typeid(var).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(str).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(integer).name() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: а как можно сделать чтобы имя типа данных выводилось полностью, а не сокращённо?

Comment: Формат вывода typeid оставлен на откуп компилятора. Но можно использовать сторонние библиотеки, например boost

Comment: @GameTime, оно и так полное выводит, если вы про то что integer назівается int, то в самом языке оно так и называется, то есть оно выводит правильное имя переменной

Answer (score 1):

Тип данных `char` поддерживает **одинарные кавычки** `''`, в то время как Вы используете двойные `""` — а они используются для типа `const char*`, как указано в описании к ошибке.

Замените двойные кавычки в коде выше на одинарные: `char str = 'a';`